# Add Pie Chart to Subplot

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dashboard of varying plots using the code below and would like to add a pie graph to the dashboard in the g11 spot.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(35,30))
spec= fig.add_gridspec(26,2, wspace =0.1, hspace=2.50)

g1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0:2, 0:1])
g2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0:2, 1:3])
....
g11 = fig.add_subplot(spec[22:26, 0:1])
g12 = fig.add_subplot(spec[22:26, 1:3])
```

The DF Im using for the pie chart looks like this:

```
        RACE_CAT  TOTAL_Volume_Percent_Race
0       Black_NH                  43.511971
1       Hispanic                  32.700009
2  Other_Unknown                  13.325381
3       White_NH                  10.462640
```

The code I wrote to add the pie graph is:

```
DF.plot(ax=g11,x='RACE_CAT', kind='pie', subplots=True, title='Volumes By Race %')
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Does anyone know more optimal code to use or how to fix the error?

Thank you!

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html

Comment: Specify the `y` column explicitly: `DF.plot(ax=g11, x='RACE_CAT', y='TOTAL_Volume_Percent_Race', kind='pie', subplots=True, title='Volumes By Race %')`

Comment: Thanks - getting an error when running this code 'AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'get_figure''. I think it has to do with the ax=g11.

Comment: Works fine on my end. What versions? I'm using `matplotlib.__version__` 3.5.1 and `pd.__version__` 1.4.2?